# Popup I want to appear once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm making a static website (no server side), I can only use HTML, CSS and some scripts.

I've made this popup script with JS that I included in each page :

```
 b=false;
    if(!b)
    {
        window.accept();
    }

   function accept()
   {


       var r = confirm('By clicking you are ready to accept condition');
        if (r == true) 
        {
            x = "You pressed OK!";
            b=true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            window.location = "http://google.com";
        } 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

   }
```

I want that popup to appear only once, thus I declared a boolean variable which takes the opposite value once the user clicks OK.
It doesn't work, the popup still shows up.

Comment: What you mean it stills shows up? you mean when you refresh the page it appears again?

Comment: Is **b** a global variable? If you do that in another function then you better use window.b everywhere

Comment: Exactly ! or when I load another page containing the script. It's the same with "certain" sites which asks the user to accept condition when entering the site, but I think I should go for cookies,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend local storage over cookies. A lot of people have cookies disabled due to vulnerability concerns. If you areworried about people using browsers that have local / session storage turned off - you can use something like Modernizr to detect that and have a fall back option.

onpage load (using checkState as the storage variable for holding this information):

```
 var checkState= localStorage.getItem('checkState');
    if(checkState=="true"){ 
    //code for accepted conditions}else
    {//code for not accepted condition};
```

on clicking the "accept" button :

```
localStorage.setItem('checkState','true');
```

Noe that local storage persists longer than session storage and so I tend to use session storage much more frequently. But both types will allow you tokeep the record of acceptance during the different page loads and do not rely on the server / network overhead of using cookies. Also - for completeness, local and session storage are not inherently safe and should not be used to store sensitive information such as passwords etc.

Comment: Perfect ! I used sessionStorage though, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

i recommend you to use cookies to check if the alert message already appeared once. you can see more details how to use it on this link: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: vote up, good anwer! and you can use localStorage instead of coockie